# What is the definition of $n\cdot n\cdot n$?

Tags: soft-question, arithmetic

Intuitively, What does it mean when you multiply numbers?
I asked my professor about what does it mean when we multiply $5\cdot 5\cdot 5$.
 He said there is no definition of this thing in mathematics.

When I was learning physics in  high school I learned about gravitational formula: $$F = G\frac{m_1m_2}{r^2} $$ Since then I was wondering what does it mean when we multiply two masses.

What does it actually mean when we multiply?

Comment: Depends on what multiplication you have in mind. Integers? Rationals? Reals? Complex numbers? Matrices? Other?

Comment: @GitGud For this question my answer is real. But want to know about all.

Comment: To know about the definition of multiplication in the real numbers you have to know the definition of rational numbers, similarly, to know about it for $\mathbb Q$, you need to know about it for the integers. In the integers it really boils down to "repeated addition". My point being that in order for this question to not be perceived as too broad, perhaps you should limit it somewhat.

Comment: Well one can view multiplication as a shorthand for addition. When we say what is $5\times 5$ we might as well say what is $5$ added to itself $5$ times.

Comment: @GitGud Ok, then  what does it mean physically when we multiply two masses?

Comment: @user1444692 Physically? As far as I'm concerned that has absolutely no meaning. Mathematics is one thing, the real world is another thing.

Comment: @GitGud. Just by curiosity : when you write *Mathematics is one thing, the real world is another thing*, is this supposed to be a joke or are you seriously thinking it ? Again, I am serious asking this question and I would really appreciate an answer. Thanks.

Comment: The definition of multiplication is relative to the context you are working in. There is no "absolute" definition. If your question is about what it means to multiply quantities, that is not a mathematical question. That is philosophy, which while interesting, is not appropriate for this site.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I was dead serious. And while it may seem obvious to some, it´s not entirely clear to all people that mathematics, at best, can *model* some parts of the real world, that they entirely different things and that any similarity between them is, too put it shortly (at the expense of perhaps being inaccurate), coincidental.

Comment: @GitGud.Very interesting point of view, indeed ! Thank you.

Comment: The density property of the rationals is a good example of how the real world and mathematics can be at odds. One can keep 'zooming in' on the real line forever and never reach a point where you have 'gaps', but this is certainly not a physical thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the beginning there were the natural numbers. If you only consider natural numbers, you can view multiplication as a shorthand for addition:

$$3 \cdot 2 = 3 + 3$$

In general $a \cdot b$ means sum $a$ a total of $b$ times, or (interestingly) sum $b$ a total of $a$ times.

After this came rational numbers (or fractions) in the form $\frac ab$; and of course you define what does it mean to sum two fractions. But now how do we define multiplication? Clearly it's not a shorthand for addition now, since you can't add a fractional numbers of terms. So people said: define

$$\frac ab \cdot \frac cd = \frac{ac}{bd}$$

Why was it defined this way? It has something to do with preserving some properties we would like an operation called "multiplication" to have (that is, we want to preserve some properties that the "original" multiplication between natural numbers had)

And in the same spirit (albeit in a little more complicated form) we define what does it mean to multiply two real numbers (again preserving the same properties we expect multiplication to have)

The main thing to take from this is that multiplication is a purely mathematical concept: it is the extension to real numbers of a concept (really, a shorthand for addition) between natural numbers, and this extension is done in a arbitrary (albeit natural) way.

Now your question is: what does it mean to multiply two masses like $m_1 m_2$? And the answer must be: *a priori* there is no physical meaning. You're just performing an abstract mathematical operation on two real numbers. As it turns out, though, this "abstract mathematical operation" is useful to *model* the way the world works. One may say that the justification for its existence is the fact that works. Notice that this is not restricted to multiplication; in physics there are thousands of mathematical operations that are constantly applied, and the fact that they work (and can be used to model our world) is something which is not clear beforehand. There is a famous paper by Nobel laureate Wigner, beautifully named [The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Mathematics in the Natural Sciences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unreasonable_Effectiveness_of_Mathematics_in_the_Natural_Sciences) which also takes on this point, among other things.

So to recap: mathematics defines abstract concepts with no intrinsic (or physical) meaning. Physics then picks them up and uses them to build the world, and for some reason it works.

Comment: Interesting paper, thanks.

Comment: +1 Nice food for thought. Maybe this suggests that since mathematics used in physics is derived from simple ideas extended to more complicated ones, and it works in physics, then the physics (or physical world itself) is also eventually built on very simple basis which happens to be compatible with those in mathematics basis...